# How can I use a "barrel file" to import extension methods?

Tags: typescript

If I define extension methods in separate files and try to import them via a barrel file, the methods never get added to the prototype.

This works:

```
import './rxjs-extensions/my-observable-extension-1';
import './rxjs-extensions/my-observable-extension-2';

//...

obs
    .extension1()
    .extension2();
```

However if I create a barrel file:

```
// rxjs-extensions/index.ts

export * from './my-observable-extension-1';
export * from './my-observable-extension-2';
```

and then try to import just the barrel

```
import './rxjs-extensions';

//...

obs
    .extension1()
    .extension2();
```

I get run-time error saying extension1 is not a function.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to barrel extension methods this way?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of trial and error later...

Apparently the barrel file shouldn't `export * from...` in this case since the individual files aren't actually exporting anything. Instead it should just import the individual files.

```
// rxjs-extensions/index.ts
import './my-observable-extension-1';
import './my-observable-extension-2';
```

and then importing the barrel works fine.

Comment: I've done it this way, but I still get runtime errors saying the function doesn't exist